# Can't remove \x strings

Tags: python-3.x, backslash, removeall

I made some researches to delete strings like \x__ . But it is not working.
Here is what i want to do:
i have a string like this:

j_r="some characters \xe2\x84\xc2 some other characters"

In my program, i only want to get:

"some characters some other characters"

Here is what i tried:

c=0

j_r=list(j_r)

```
while c < len(j_r):

     if j_r[c]=='\\':
          c+=3
     j_f.append(j_r[c])
     c+=1
print(j_f)
```

And here is what it prints:

> > > ['s','o','m','e',' ','c','h','a','r','a','c','t','e','r','s']

So i lost the second part of the string that i wanted to keep :'(
May someone help please. 
Thank you very much.
(sorry for my english... i am french)

Comment: Are you sure that's what the string contains exactly? Your code assumes otherwise. Please print the representation of the string (`print(repr(...))`) and attach it.

Comment: I get the same. Exactly, here is the string. It is taken from steam html code:  b'\t\t\t\t\t\t<span class="title">Battlefield: Bad Company\xe2\x84\xa2 2</span>\r\n'. I have some conditions to restrict this to: Battlefield: Bad Company\xe2\x84\xa2 2. But the condition of the example to delete the \x__ is not working, and when i print, i get: "B,""a","t","t","l","e","f","i","e","l","d"," ","B","a","d"," ","C","o","m","p","a","n","y"

Comment: So here, the '2' is missing, but for a game like assassin's creed Unity, i only got 'A','s','s','a','s','s','i','n'

Comment: See that "b" at the beginning? It's completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking out this code.

The hex variables that you have created should first be checked since \xe2 is treated as on character.

```
j_r="some characters \xe2\x84\xc2 some other characters"
c=0

j_r=list(j_r)

j_f = list()
print('Hello World!')
while c < len(j_r):
     a = int(j_r[c].encode('hex'), 16)
     if(a == 32 or ((a >= 65 and a <= 90)or ( a >= 97 and a<= 122))):
            j_f.append(j_r[c])
     c += 1
print(j_f)
```

I hope this code help you with your problem.

Comment: No, it shows: 'Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Mathieu/Desktop/PROJET-INFO/test area.py", line 9, in <module>
    a = int(j_r[c].encode('hex'), 16)
LookupError: unknown encoding: hex

Comment: Maybe i need to import a python library?

Comment: I am just using the generic python libraries. Actually, the code that I have presented was the actual code that I used for the Python console.

Answer (score 0):

What you're getting is bytes, and you want text from it. Therefore you need to [decode](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) it.

```
3>> b'Battlefield: Bad Company\xe2\x84\xa2 2'.decode('utf-8')
'Battlefield: Bad Company™ 2'
```